# Nuxt Vue, как сделать глобальную переменную для токена?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

В store есть state который содержит boolean token, что бы его получить приходится делать такой запрос: this.$store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated'] . Есть ли способ сделать его в виде функции или переменной?
Сейчас это работает так:

```
<button v-if="this.$store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']" class="admin-button ">Админское действие</button>
```

Хочется просто в v-if короткую переменную цеплять, что бы не приходилось при этом на каждой странице создавать функцию для этого.

Должно быть например так:

```
<button v-if="isAdmin" class="admin-button ">Админское действие</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/

Создать в папке plugins>token.js содержит код:

```
export default ({ store }, inject) => {
  inject('isAdmin', () => { return store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']
})}
```

В nuxt.config.js:

```
plugins: [
    '@/plugins/token'
],
```

В шаблоне:

```
<button v-if="$isAdmin()" class="admin-button ">Админское действие</button>
```